# Excel VBA recommendation

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am using a formula which will calculate a value using index and match and the output is subtracting from another cell B2 value.I need to keep `B2` as common subtracting component across all cell

I am using below formula in cell `C2`

```
=IFERROR(B2-(INDEX(raw!$A:$D,MATCH(1,(raw!$A:$A=data!$A2)*(raw!$C:$C=data!C$1),0),4)),"")
```

[image]

But If I drag this formula to next cell, `D2` The formula is getting change to

```
=IFERROR(C2-(INDEX(raw!$A:$D,MATCH(1,(raw!$A:$A=data!$A2)*(raw!$C:$C=data!D$1),0),4)),"")
```

`C2` is replacing `B2`

[image]

I want to keep `B2` as constant

Below is the VBA macro created :

```
Sub Macro7()
'
' Macro7 Macro
'
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=IFERROR(RC[-1]-(INDEX(raw!C1:C4,MATCH(1,(raw!C1=data!RC1)*(raw!C3=data!R1C),0),4)),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:D1"), Type:= _
        xlFillDefault
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:D1").Select
End Sub
```

If I manually edit the formula in each cell, it is working fine (changing, `C2,D2,E3,F2` etc to `B2`). But I am using this formula in 100s of cells and manually editing all is not practically possible. Is there anyway I can change the VBA to keep B2 as constant across the range of cell to run this formula ?

Comment: why don't you use `=IFERROR($B$2-...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for the anchor cell in a formula feature in Excel. This can be done by adding a "$" dollar sign in the formula. So change "B2" to "$B$2" and that should keep B2 anchored when you copy your formula.

I'm not sure how or if this will convert to VBA well, but I figured this might point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question has already been answered, but that I have something to add to your understanding...

If you want to replicate the semi-static $B2 reference when entering a formula using the R1C1 reference style, you should change

```
=IFERROR(RC[-1]...
```

to

```
=IFERROR(RC2...
```

The RC[-1] in the first example places a dynamic reference to the same row and 1 column to the left, whereas RC2 places a semi-static reference to the same row and always the 2nd column.

What confuses me is that this whole line has a mix of R1C1 references and standard references:

```
"=IFERROR(RC[-1]-(INDEX(raw!C1:C4,MATCH(1,(raw!C1=data!RC1)*(raw!C3=data!R1C),0),4)),"""")"
```